# F# how to AddHandler alike VB.NET

Tags: f#

VB.NET code is  :

```
AddHandler TheGrp.DataChanged, AddressOf theGrp_DataChange
```

So how can I do same with F# ?

```
theGrp.DataChanged.AddHandler(X.theGrp_DataChange)
```

Error   1   This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `theGrp.DataChanged.AddHandler(fun o e -> X.theGrp_DataChange(o, e))`.  The signature for `AddHandler` indicates that it takes a delegate, so you can either explicitly create one (via something like `DataChangedEventHandler(fun o e -> X.theGrp_DataChange(o, e))`) or you can let the compiler implicitly add the delegate constructor when given a function definition, but you can't just use the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a lambda expression explicitly, you can also write (In this case, the function signature matches the signature required by the delegate, so it should work):

```
theGrp.DataChanged.AddHandler(DataChangedEventHandler(x.theGrp_DataChanged))
```

Also, if you don't need the *sender* argument, you can declare the `theGrp_DataChanged` method to take only the *event args* argument and then write just:

```
theGrp.DataChanged.Add(x.theGrp_DataChanged)
```